# JPA Select query not returning results with one letter word

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a query that when given a word that starts with a one-letter word followed by space character and then another word (ex: "T Distribution"), does not return results. While given "Distribution" alone returns results including the results for "T Distribution". It is the same behavior with all search terms beginning with a one-letter word followed by space character and then another word.

The problem appears when the search term is of this pattern:
"[one-letter][space][letter/word]". example: "o ring".

What would be the problem that the LIKE operator not working correctly in this case?

Here is my query:

```
@Cacheable(value = "filteredConcept")
@Query("SELECT NEW sina.backend.data.model.ConceptSummaryVer04(s.id, s.arabicGloss, s.englishGloss, s.example, s.dataSourceId,
s.synsetFrequnecy, s.arabicWordsCache, s.englishWordsCache, s.superId, s.categoryId, s.dataSourceCacheAr, s.dataSourceCacheEn,
s.superTypeCasheAr, s.superTypeCasheEn, s.area, s.era, s.rank, s.undiacritizedArabicWordsCache, s.normalizedEnglishWordsCache, 
s.isTranslation, s.isGloss, s.arabicSynonymsCount, s.englishSynonymsCount) FROM Concept s 
where s.undiacritizedArabicWordsCache LIKE %:searchTerm% AND data_source_id != 200 AND data_source_id != 31")
List<ConceptSummaryVer04> findByArabicWordsCacheAndNotConcept(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, Sort sort);
```

the result of the query on the database itself:
[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zzdf.png)

results on the database are returned no matter the letters case:
[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0InE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.
It was due to the default configuration of the Full-text index on mysql database which is by default set to 2 (`ft_min_word_len = 2`).

I changed that and rebuilt the index. Then, one-letter words were returned by the query.

[12.9.6 Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length)

Answer (score 0):

Use some quotes:

```
 LIKE '%:searchTerm%';
```

Comment: do you even get an error of any kind? or just that the result set does not return what you expect ?

Comment: ok, notice that in your data you have to have entries for which that field is something like `%T Distribution%`, do you have data that verifiy that ?

Comment: I have. I tried querying the database directly and it is there. In addition if I searched the term "Distribution" using the website, it returns results including the results for "T Distribution". So definitely it is there in the database.

Comment: ok that's weird, try to execute your query by giving `T D` as a search term

Comment: no results searching "T D". I noticed it happens when the searched term is as this: "<one-letter><space><letter/word>"

Comment: even with quotes ?

Comment: When I search for "T" however, it returns results for "T Distribution". Weird. Isn't it?

Comment: Even with quotes.

Comment: try using "_ %" underscore then space and then percentage symbol in your search expression, that will give you all words having single letter followed by space and then some word

Comment: OK, try to change the query : remove the wildcards from it and pass the entrie expression with the wildcards while invoking it, `LIKE ':searchTerm'`, and invoke it like this `findByArabicWordsCacheAndNotConcept("%T Distribution%");`

Comment: I tried "_ %", it returned an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist

Comment: I tried passing the the wildcards with the expression. didn't work. even for one words such as "time" that weren't a problem before.

Comment: Just provide a screenshot of your table, especially that weird column

Comment: I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Ok, I see that this is just a case sensitive issue, `T Distribution` is not the same as `t Distribution`

Comment: If you want to ignore cases just add the upper case keyword aggregator: `... where UPPER(s.undiacritizedArabicWordsCache) LIKE UPPER('%:searchTerm%')`

Comment: Tried that. didn't work too. in addition, LIKE was case-insensitive on the database itself. See attached screenshot.

Comment: yes. every possible form. no results. this is the same behavior for other terms such as "o group", "o level", "o ring" which are all lower-case in both the database and the search query. No results either. the problem is with the pattern: <one-letter><space><letter/word>

Comment: That is so weird o.o

Answer (score 0):

Set `searchTerm="%your_word%"` and use it on query like this :

```
... s.undiacritizedArabicWordsCache LIKE :searchTerm ...
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is space character? It might be another character (\t, \n etc.)

Comment: I am very sure. it is a space in both the database and the searched term.

Comment: Can you print length of  the queried column on the sql query on screenshots. I am still thinking there might be extra unprintable characters. Also queries on screenshots using english column, but column on the question arabic.